# Incorrect result for parallel run to calculate a Do loop?

Tags: parallelization

I want to calculate the following Do loop

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pmat = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4}];
ParallelDo[pmat[[i, j]] = i*j, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
pmat
```

However, the result is all 0 while the right result has some places to be nonzero. Do I wrongly use ParallelDo? Also, `Parallelize` does not work in this case.

Comment: This is explained in **Possible Issues** section of document of `ParallelDo`. You need to `SetSharedVariable[pmat]`.